# VS.net reports conflict between "System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0" and "System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.3" (SOLVED)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dependencies, nuget

I have troubles understanding what Visual Studio tries to tell me:

```js
There was a conflict between "System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" and "System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51".
    "System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" was not.
    References which depend on "System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" [C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\7.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll].
        C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\7.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\7.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll".
            C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\7.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll
    References which depend on "System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" [].
        C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.json\7.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.json\7.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll".
            C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.json\7.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll
        C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencymodel\7.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencymodel\7.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll".
            C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencymodel\7.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll
            C:\Users\martin\.nuget\packages\serilog.settings.configuration\7.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Serilog.Settings.Configuration.dll  sbackend
```

What i understand:

- There are 2 versions of System.Text.Json: 7.0.0.0 and 7.0.0.3
- 7.0.0.0 is chosen, because "primary"
- 2 dependencies require 7.0.0.3

What i dont understand:

- Where is the 7.0.0.0 dependency coming from?
- Why is 7.0.0.0 primary?
- The .csproj file references version "7.0.3" - why is there 1 digit missing?

```js
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json">
      <Version>7.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

**EDIT: SOLVED**
Removing the autogenerated bindingRedirect from App.config solved this issue for me.

```
-      <dependentAssembly>
-        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
-        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.3" newVersion="7.0.0.3" />
-      </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Do you mean jsproj, or csproj? Can you provide a [mcve] (probably just a project file) which shows the problem?

Comment: Some other packages or components in the project are using version 7.0.0.0 of System.Text.Json. It may not be referenced directly in your .csproj file, but it may be pulled in as a transitive dependency by another package. You can try removing the automatically generated bindingRedirect from App.config and rebuild the project